# How does mongoDB stitch compares with Parse Server and firebase?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mongodb-stitch

Im looking for a complete backend solution but I haven't been able to find information on how does mongoDB Stitch compares to other alternatives. In general I feel like I like the product but I worry about the long term support.